# how to combine values in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

How to combine values (strings) in XPath?
Say we've got something like this:

```
<entry>
  <x>value1</x>
  <y>value2</y>
</entry>
```

How would I accomplish `entry/value1 + entry/value2`
I'm looking for the substitue of this in PHP:

```
$result = $value1 . $value2
```

Also, is it possible to combine with a predefined string that's not from the XML?
Like:

```
$result = 'prefix' . $value1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath's `concat` function may prove useful: `concat('prefix',/entry/x,/entry/y)`